# При редактировании поста с картинкой в базе данных имя картинки удаляется

Tags: php, html, база-данных, изображения, input

В input file не подтягивается файл, из-за чего пробрасывается пустота и удаляется прошлое имя. Как решить проблему?

Это первый код, не бейте тапками). Я пробовал разные костыли, зарание прокидывал в $_POST, $_GET, в сам запрос $post_param имя изображения - не выходит. Как вариант можно как-нибудь от name в input file избавлятся при отсутствии $_POST['img'] чтоб не пробрасывался, но как?

```
// Обнавить пост

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET' && isset($_GET['id'])){

$postInfo = selectOne('posts', ['id' => $_GET['id']]);
$id = $postInfo['id'];
$title = $postInfo['title'];
$content = $postInfo['content'];
$img_name = $postInfo['img'];
$status = $postInfo['status'];
$topic = $postInfo['id_topics'];
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['up_post'])){

$id = $_POST['id'];
$title = trim($_POST['title_up_post']);
$content = trim($_POST['text_up_post']);
$status = isset($_POST['statusPost']) != 0 ? 1 : 0;
$topic_post = trim($_POST['topic_up_post']);

if (!empty($_FILES['img']['name'])){
    $img_name = $_FILES['img']['name']."_".time();
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
    $destination = SITE_ROOT . '\assets\img\posts\\' . $img_name;
    $file_type = mime_content_type($fileTmpName);
    if(strpos($file_type, 'image') === false){
        array_push($errMsg, 'можно загружать только изображения');
    }
    $resultImg = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $destination);
    if($resultImg){
        $_POST['img'] = $img_name;
        $img_name .= time();
    } else{
        array_push($errMsg, "Ошибка загрузки изображения на сервер");
    }
}

if($title === '' || $content === '' || $topic_post === ''){
    array_push($errMsg, 'Не все поля заполнены');
} else if (mb_strlen($title) < 7){
    array_push($errMsg, 'Название статьи должно быть не меньше 7 символов');
} else{
    $post_param = [
        'title' => $title,
        'content' => $content,
        'img' => $img_name,
        'id_topics' => $topic_post,
        'status' => $status
    ];

    update('posts', $id, $post_param);
    header("Location: ".BASE_URL1.'/admin/posts/index.php');
}
}
```

Comment: Очевидно - не обновлять поле если не загружен файл.

Comment: А покажите код HTML и обработчика?

Comment: Ну и теперь если `$img_name` пуст, то его не следует добавлять в `$post_param`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо дело в том, что в форме вы не правильно передаёте имя картинки.

То есть код в условии не выполняется:

```php
if (!empty($_FILES['img']['name'])) {}
```

Соответственно, и переменная `$img_name` не определятся.

Вот что получается, когда вы обновляете пост:

```php
$post_param = [
    'title' => $title,
    'content' => $content,
    'img' => $img_name, // Переменная не определена, то есть вы передаёте false
    'id_topics' => $topic_post,
    'status' => $status
];
```

Поэтому имя изображения и удаляется.

Как вариант, одно из простейших решений:

```php
$post_param = [
    'title' => $title,
    'content' => $content,
    'id_topics' => $topic_post,
    'status' => $status
];

if (!empty($img_name)) {
    $post_param['img'] = $img_name;
}

update('posts', $id, $post_param);
```

Comment: Я вроде пробовал так, но видимо не так. Спасибо!